# FreePascal mouse input when using graph window?

Tags: graph, mouse, freepascal

GetMouseX does not work when using a graph window.

```
uses wincert,graph,winmouse;
var x,y:integer;
Begin
x:=GetMouseX;
End.
```

This gives me Error:Identifier not found "GetMouseX".
Trying this with unit 'mouse' works in the console window, but not in the graphics window.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I managed to find a list of functions for winmouse. The page was in... Polish or something, but the example code worked like a charm.

```
uses graph, wincrt, winmouse;
var gd,gm: integer;
    ch:char;
    i:integer;
    mposx, mposy, state: longint;
begin
 gd := d4bit;
 gm := m640x480;
 initgraph(gd,gm,'');
 initmouse;
 randomize;
 for i:=1 to 10 do
   circle(random(640),random(480),150);
 repeat
   if keypressed then ch:= readkey;
   if lpressed then
     begin
     repeat until not lpressed;
     getmousestate(mposx,mposy,state);
     if getpixel(mposx,mposy)<15 then
       begin
       setfillstyle(solidfill,random(14)+1);
       floodfill(mposx,mposy,15);
       end;
     end;
 until ch = #27;
 closegraph;
end.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, winmouse is not a version/subset of mouse like wincrt is a subset of crt for windows "graph" use..

It is just an unit to let mouse work with graph. Look at the unit to see what functions are available (lpressed,rpressed,getlastbuttonpress etc)